# Error in map_GIS %>% filter(Disability == "Cerebral palsy") %>% cat["AgeatDeath" >

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Using the code below, I am trying to generate a new character variable (cat) using a numeric variable (AgeatDeath). I am getting this: could not find function "%>%<-" while the dplyr is loaded. map_GIS is my data.
Thanks,
Nader

```
map_GIS %>%
filter(Disability=='Cerebral palsy')  %>%
cat ['AgeatDeath' > 40] <- "Elder"
```

Comment: I think the assignment `<-` wouldn't work there. May be you need `map_GIS %>% filter(Diasbility == 'Cerebral palsy') %>% mutate(cat = case_when(AgeatDeath > 40 ~ 'Elder'))`

Comment: Why? what is wrong? Any alternatives?

Comment: Because you mixing and matching base and tidyverse, in the tidyverse in order to create new columns you use mutate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to create a new column, named 'cat' (`cat` is a function name as well), we can use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
map_GIS2 <- map_GIS %>%
              filter(Disability == 'Cerebral palsy') %>%
               mutate(cat = case_when(AgeatDeath > 40 ~ 'Elder'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I got a new error: Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x object 'Diasbility' not found
ℹ Input `..1` is `Diasbility == "Cerebral palsy"`.

Comment: @NaderMehri sorry, that was a typo in my code.  it should be `Disability` instead of `Diasbility`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How can I do this with if statement instead of filter function?

Comment: @NaderMehri You meant without the `filter` step?  Then you need `&` condition i.e. `map_GIS %>% mutate(cat = case_when(AgeatDeath > 40 & Disability == 'Cerebral palsy' ~ 'Elder'))`

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what I needed! How can I replace the values of cat if AgeatDeath < 40 & Disability == 'Cerebral palsy'  ~ 'Younger'. I tried the code below but it did not work: map_GIS <- map_GIS %>%
  mutate(cat = case_when(AgeatDeath > 40 & Disability == 'Cerebral palsy'  ~ 'Elder')) %>%
  cat = case_when(AgeatDeath < 40 & Disability == 'Cerebral palsy'  ~ 'Younger')

Comment: You can have multiple statements in `case_when` i.e `map_GIS %>% mutate(cat = case_when(AgeatDeath > 40 & Disability == 'Cerebral palsy' ~ 'Elder', AgeatDeath < 40 & Disability == 'Cerebral palsy' ~ 'Younger'))`